# Facebook graph API, FB.api post on custom action fails first time but succeeds second time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have started dabbling with Facebook Graph api fairly recently. I have defined a custom action 'Start' with the namespace 'Test', here is the code I use to for posting to Facebook.

```
FB.api('/me/Test:start',{ article : currentURL, message: $j('.subject-content h2 a').html()}, 'post', function(response) {

                                  if (!response || response.error) {
                                       console.log('Error  '+response.error.message);
                                  }
                                  else {
                                       console.log('Message was posted! (post id: ' + response.id + ")");
                                  }
                             });
```

for some reason this post fails the first time, but on subsequent tries, the post succeeds.

Here are the requests I captured from firebug.

1)

```
        access_token    xxxxx
        article https://testserver:8080/xxx
        callback    FB._callbacks.__gcb2
        message testpage
        method  post
        pretty  0
        sdk joey
```

2)

```
    access_token    yyyy
    article https://testserver:8080/xxx
    callback    FB._callbacks.__gcb6
    message testpage
    method  post
    pretty  0
    sdk joey
```

As you can see the calls are exactly the same. The first time I get this response

```
/**/ FB._callbacks.__gcb4({"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}});
```

I tried the same requests on the graph explorer as well, it works every single time.

Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. I was executing two post request simultaneously and this one would consistently keep failing, so I thought there was some problem with this request.

```
FB.api('/me/Test:start .... );
FB.api('/me/feed .... );
```

I don't know what the problem was but when I separated these two requests. Everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting wasn't clear from the Question, that said:

I'm reasonably sure using `localhost` object URLs isn't going to work, you should test with a domain that's accessible by Facebook's crawler - the crawler needs to read the page and the meta tags on it to create the object in Facebook's graph

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am not using localhost. I am testing this on a public domain. I just replaced the test environment url's with dummy url's